# How can I save a user specifig config in a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, config

I am trying to build a CLI with node (using commander.js) and I would like to save user specific configuration, so that a user only has to enter it on the first usage. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to a hidden file in, say, `~/.mycliconfig` and the just read the file synchronously

```
try{
  var userData = fs.readFileSync(process.env.HOME + '/.mycliconfig');
} catch(e){
  if (e.code === 'ENOENT') {
    console.log('File not found!');
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

If you need to save more stuff you can always create a wrapper folder and drop all files in there.